# mysql - displaying values from columnA by values in columnB

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I'm trying to create a query in MySql that joins two tables and displays values from both.

TableA:

```
id | value
----------
 1 |   123
 2 |   456
 3 |   789
```

TableB:

```
id | key | value | type
-----------------------
 1 |   1 |    10 |  'A'
 2 |   1 |    11 |  'B'
 3 |   2 |    12 |  'A'
 4 |   2 |    13 |  'B'
 5 |   2 |    14 |  'C'
 6 |   3 |    15 |  'A'
 7 |   3 |    16 |  'B'
```

The tables join on `TableA.id = TableB.key`. I want to display `TableA.id`, `TableB.value` - however I only care about values from TableB of type `C`. If there's no type 'C' entry, then I want to display `null` (doesn't matter what it really is, can be actually null or just a string saying 'null'). For the above example, I would expect the result to be:

```
ID | Value
----------
1  |  null
2  |    14
3  |  null
```

So far I haven't been able to come up with anything - everything I've tried either doesn't grab any data, or displays too much. Closest I've conceptually come is:

```
select TA.id as 'ID', TB.value as 'Value'
from TableA TA
left join TableB TB on TA.id = TB.key
where TB.type = 'C';
```

However this would only result in:

```
ID | Value
----------
 2 |    14
```

And would omit ID's `1` and `3`. Any help here would be appreciated!

**NOTE: I realize there would be better ways to organize these tables to make this easy. Alas, I don't control the db structure/schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, WHEREs happen after JOINs (mostly):

```
SELECT TA.id AS 'ID', TB.value AS 'Value'
FROM TableA AS TA
LEFT JOIN TableB TB AS TA.id = TB.key AND TB.type = 'C'
;
```

*And nothing about the table structure stood out as bad to me.*

Comment: exactly what I was looking for - thanks for the lightning fast reply!

Comment: I was posting exactly the same